# Find int after a colon (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the value of an integer inputted the user before and after a colon. I've figured out how to retrieve the first value, but if the value after the colon is more than one character it will only grab the first.

```
startingWeight = input(("Starting weight of food (in lbs:ozs)="))
endingWeight = input(("Ending weight of food (in lbs:ozs="))

startingWeightPos = startingWeight.find(":")
endingWeightPos = endingWeight.find(":")

startingWeightPounds = startingWeight[0:startingWeightPos]
startingWeightOz = startingWeight[1:startingWeightPos]

endingWeightPounds = endingWeight[0:endingWeightPos]
endingWeightOz = endingWeight[1:endingWeightPos]

print (startingWeightPounds)
print (endingWeightPounds)
print (startingWeightOz)
print (endingWeightOz)
```

Comment: The slices should be `[:pos]` and `[pos+1:]`. Or you could just use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: you can do `.split(":")` on the string

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to get what is on the left and on the right side of the `:`.

```
text = '100:66'
text_split = text.split(":")

lbs = text_split[0]
ozs = text_split[1]
```

Convert these to float using `float()` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use slices, the two slices would be `[:pos]` (everything up to `pos`), and `[pos+1:]` (everything after `pos`).

E.g.

```
pos = pounds.index(':')
pounds = weight[:pos]
oz = weight[pos+1:]
```

But the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function exists to make this simpler.

```
pounds, oz = weight.split(':')
```